# How does one view system changes comparing before and after an application installation?

Tags: log

I would like to see a diff. of my Ubuntu system - including all new directories, files, and file changes - comparing the state before vs. after an application installation. How would I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Check these and you may find what your looking for:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info
/var/log/dpkg.log
/var/log/aptitude
```

But aptitude logging is notoriously inadequate.

Comment: This fails to account for the effects of preinst, postinst, and configure scripts.  If it's a one-off job, inspect those scripts to see what they do; for a more systematic approach, perhaps hack `dpkg` to `strace` them?  (Maybe it has already been done.)

Comment: I would like something that is decoupled from any package management tool so that I can see changes after installing software from source. Thanks.

Comment: That would be completely dependant on the source you are installing then, and if that source even creates a log file.  Linux does not track these things (by default) like say windows event viewer does.  You can have custom logging packages but thats up to the user to install.  /var/log holds a lot of good info too, check out /var/log/messages or /var/log/dmesg.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't that what [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) does?

Comment: Does anyone have any experience using Tripwire thus?